# How to simulate click event on an input box

Tags: javascript

I am trying to simulate click on an input box. When its clicked manually, a drop down auto suggestion box appears as suggestions about past searches. However, when I try to simulate the click programmatically, I'm getting the error that 'object doesn't support click method'. Is there any other way to do this? All I want is the click event and the auto suggestion box to drop down. Btw, this is Gmail's Search Mail input box on their mailbox that I am trying to play around with through web console.

I have tried to call click function through className, but it gives me the error of either undefined or object doesn't support click. This is the widget that I am talking about:

```
  <input name="q" class="gb_cf" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="gs_sbt50" aria-live="off"  dir="ltr" spellcheck="false" aria-label="Search mail" type="text" placeholder="Search mail" value="" autocomplete="off">

  <input disabled="" class="gb_cf" id="gs_taif50" dir="ltr" autocomplete="off">
```

Few things that I have tried:

```
    document.getElementbyClassName("gb_cf")[0].click(); 
    document.getElementbyName("q")[0].click();
    document.getElementbyId("gs_taif50").click();
```

None of them work. Any ideas?

Comment: can you write the code that you did in javascript

Comment: You probably need focus instead of click.

Comment: Hi Sascha, I have tried focus. The problem with focus is that it is not giving me the auto suggestions drop down that only appears with a click.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`.focus()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp) instead of `.click()`

```
document.getElementbyClassName("gb_cf")[0].focus(); //or
document.getElementbyId("gs_taif50").focus();
```

Comment: I tried this. It is still not simulating a click, as I am not getting the auto suggestions drop-down to appear with the focus command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **pure/native javascript**, you can use the [`onfocus`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onfocus.asp) attribute of the `input` element to call a Js function.

```html
<script>
    function showButton(){
    document.getElementById('mybutt').style.display = "block";
}
</script>

<body>
    <input id="myinp" type="text" placeholder="place" onfocus="javascript:showButton()"/> 
    <button id="mybutt" style="display:none;">OK</button>
</body>
```

In the above file, you should see the "OK" button appear when you click on the input field.

Comment: I can't edit the code to add the onfocus attribute.

Comment: @user5938020 You can. Just right click on the line in the inspector (that you want to edit) and select **Edit as HTML**. [Here's a picture](https://i.imgur.com/CTevpZg.png) of how it looks like in Brave/Chrome.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57315112/how-to-click-on-search-mail-input-box-in-gmail for a better explanation of the question. I posted this today hoping to get some answers.

Comment: I now seriously think that browsers don't allow such modifications to come into effect. You can, perhaps, edit the html to see some difference in structure/style but Js isn't allowed. In that case, you wouldn't be able to achieve what you're trying to.